# best practice json?

Tags: json, spring, rest, spring-mvc

when using spring rest server side generate json, it will looks like below

```
{"userInfo":{"id":123,"userFullName":"full name"}}    with nested 'userInfo'
```

should json generate this way is consider best practice or should just generate like below

`{"id":88,"userFullName":"dfXXXXXXXXXX"}`    without nested 'userinfo'

the reason i asking is, if i use the prior technique, on my client, i would need to Extract the user info as JSONObject then only can get json data . which way is better?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is like asking which is better between these two xml fragmetns:

```
<userinfo>
  <id></id>
  <username></username>
</userinfo>
```

or

```
<id></id>
<username></username>
```

I would prefer the first format because it's more readable, but of course, there's less data generated from the second format. Best practice is to have a code that's maintainable. So just like what **yoda** answered

> "From a code mantainer point of view,
>   I would choose the first option"

Answer (score 2):

From a maintenance point of view, I would choose the first option, since you might need extra information latter. Apart from that, there's not much difference.

Comment: can elaborate more your argument. because when we use rest, the path will tell what restul will be return right. like http://site/get/user_pojo  show it use to get user info ?  secondly, i cant find way to make spring-rest, dont put the nested userinfo

Comment: @cometta, are you using @ResponseBody and Jackson?

Comment: @cometta, you can actually. Visit this related tutorial: http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/jqgrid-and-spring-3-mvc-integration.html . Check the part where I created a custom POJO that was converted automatically to JSON. I know it's a tutorial for a different concern but it proves that you can actually send that userinfo without the userinfo tag

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe either solution is universally more correct than the other. I think the more appropriate solution heavily depends on the context.

With that being said, in my humble opinion, while the first solution as you mention requires more processing, it also offers a lot more flexibility. JSON is great for representing data hierarchy and structure. If you ever wanted to add in more data or structure, I believe the first solution (with the nested userInfo) would handle the transition more smoothly.

For example let's say you wanted to support the info for multiple users, then the only switch you would need to make is to have userInfo contain a JSON array of multiple userInfo objects. To take this a step further, let's say you also wanted include a new set of data entirely - say locationInfo - you would benefit from the nested hierarchy to separate out these two different classes of data.

Ultimately, I believe that the right solution is the one that is most appropriate to the context of your application but I would encourage you to be forward thinking in how you approach your design and try to anticipate how you might use this implementation in the future.

Just food for thought.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

JSON's core tenet is to provide "object-oriented" notations to be used within JavaScript. and if you stick by that, i feel that your first construct, having nested `userInfo` is a more appropriate construct. otherwise, in the second case, you'll end up having to build the `userInfo` object from the other field data.